# Is there a better way to plot interactive 3d graphs using pandas, bokeh, or python on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am processing x, y, and z data to have a floor map with high and lows. Z being a displacement sensor. I am having some difficulty plotting a good representation of my data. I am also fairly new to pandas and python in general. I have tried doing a contour plot with no luck, and I have only been able to plot my data using matplotlib as a 3d scatter as below. I tried looking into Bokeh as well using the surface3d extension, but I have not been successful. I would want to have my data shown in either a interactive 3d scatter or wireframe with gradients, and a contour plot. Thank you in advance!

[Jupyter Notebook Code. Omit comments. They are previous graphing attempts.]

[image: 1]

[Jupyter Notebook Graph Result]

[image: 2]

Comment: You use `%matplotlib nbagg` in notebook and `%matplotlib ipympl` in both notebook and lab. Those should make the matplotlib 3d plots interactive

Comment: for ipympl you will also need to `pip install ipympl`

Comment: Thank you. Just added it in, and it works! Is there a way to generate the plot in a much larger scale? It currently outputs in a tiny window under the cell. I would like to be able to analyze it with gradients in max and min points.

Comment: I see on the ipympl figure plot, that I am able to download. It does not work though. Is there a way to download it?

Comment: with ipympl there's a handle in th ebottom right that you can drag to make it bigger, you can also make the figure bigger. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70539176/835607

Comment: I see. Thanks! What about downloading it, so I can send it to someone else? I would want it to be interactive for them without having them running Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: HoloViews provides simple wrappers around Plotly's surface plotting components, which export to standalone HTML that's fully interactive. See e.g. http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/plotly/Surface.html

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry I was new at the time